# How MotionLayout KeyCycle works?

Tags: android, android-motionlayout

My motionScene file has

```
     <KeyCycle
            motion:motionTarget="@+id/textView5"
            motion:framePosition="10"
            motion:waveShape="sin"
            motion:wavePeriod="1"
            android:rotation="90"
            motion:waveOffset="0" />
```

As a result my button is shaking the whole way from starting point and it starts faster and then getting to end it slows down .And I don't understand in this case if the animation starts from 0 position what framePosition stands for or what wavePeriod stands for?